# Z-Index not working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I  had created dialogue box at the time of Delete button click.It is overlaying parent Div.

Its working in all browsers except IE 7.Here I mentioned Css for dialog box and div.

```
dialog_box {
width:219px;
height:100px;
background-image:url(../images/preference/popup.png); background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding:10px;
position:absolute;
right:-10px;
z-index:50;
overflow:hidden;
}

Div{
border:solid 1px #ffffff;
padding:10px;
padding-left:30px;
padding-top:10px;
padding-bottom:10px;
position:relative;
text-align:left;
}
```

Any idea why its happening?

Comment: you should tag this with IE too...it will be interesting to see some day how many questions the beast has generated

Answer (score 5):

It's hard without seeing the HTML, and I'm not sure how the iframe will affect this, but it seems like the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896998/z-index-in-ie-6-and-ie-7/), so Davidyn is probably right.

I've got a post on [IEs z-indexing](http://thatnorwegianguy.wordpress.com/2007/11/29/positioning-and-z-index-in-ie/) (**Update:** new and live link)  with some illustrations which might bring you closer to a solution.

The article is now down so here is the [wayback machine's archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090105222100/http://thatnorwegianguy.com/positioning-and-z-index-in-ie/)

Comment: @Allen yes, sorry. My WP install got hacked and I haven't had the time to get a new one up. Have updated the answer with a new link.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the z-index on the position:relative elements (and not on the absolute elements within it if you have any).

Also note that when setting the z-index for a positioned element, a new z-order stack will be created for the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Is the element referenced by dialog_box in the same container as Div? In IE, dealing with z-index for elements contained within the same containing block can be quirky at times. Try moving your dialog_box out to a higher-level containing block (say the body element), and see how that works. You might need to adjust your positioning, but usually putting popup divs at body level alleviates any quirky z-index/absolute positioning behavior.

Comment: No, dialog box created after the parent Div end place.Both are different Divs

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue with IE7.

See this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/64774ff1-1cce-4666-a2c7-9a899994aaef

Or google "IE7 z-index" and find out much more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are going for here... I guess the DIV under dialog_box ?

It might be that you did not define a z-index for the DIV, see if giving that a 40 works.

Comment: Yes I added dialog box after the parent Div(Both are in Iframe ) using Jquery. I set z-index for the parent Div.But Same thing only happened.

Comment: Hmm.. you might have to try a javascript solution.. something like

http://richa.avasthi.name/blogs/tepumpkin/2008/01/11/ie7-lessons-learned/

Answer (score 0):

It is the best way will help you. use jquery

```
$(function() {
   var zIndexNumber = 1000;
   $(".x").each(function() {
           $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
           zIndexNumber -= 10;
   });
});
```

style

> .rel{     width:50px;     height:50px;    background-color:#333;
>     position:relative; } .abs{  position:absolute;  top:34px;   left:5px;
>     background-color:#FFF;  height:20px;    width:30px; }

Html

```
<div class="rel"><div class="abs"></div></div>
```